# smaller than sign between underbraced expressions

Tags: equations, underbrace, compare

[image: How to include smaller than sign between underbraced expressions]

How to include smaller than sign between underbraced expressions

Comment: Could you provide your code for the expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems a decent positioning

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Ex}{\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}

\[
\max_{w} U=
 \underbrace{\pi \Ex_{\theta_1} u (w'r)}_{S(\theta_1)}
 \underset{\substack{\vphantom{\underbrace{\scriptstyle\mathstrut}}\\<}}{+}
 \underbrace{(1-\pi)\Ex_{\theta_2} u (w'r)}_{S(\theta_2)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the definition for `\Ex` (use whatever name you like) that doesn't have the bad side effect of the E being lowered. Also note that the correct input is `w'`, not `w^{'}`; don't use `\left` and `\right` in this case.